# iframe image http to https

Tags: image, iframe, tabs

I am trying to create my first iframe tab in Facebook. Every time I try to add in a photo code (it is http and shows up properly in preview) it tells me it must be https, so I change it manually and then it will only show as a broken thumbnail file in the preview? Frustrated! Help please!